# what is the error in my python script that cause an infinite loop

Tags: python, path, pyqt5, infinite-loop

i have a python class that create a window that includes

- EditLine
- open button
- cancel button

where the EditLine will  get the userInput  that is a path for folder.

the problem is that once i run the script it enter in infinite loop.

## code:

```
'''
1- import the libraries from the converted file
2- import the converted file 
'''
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import pathmsgbox 
import os 
import pathlib

class path_window(pathmsgbox.Ui_PathMSGbox):


    def __init__(self,windowObject ):
        self.windowObject = windowObject
        self.setupUi(windowObject)
        self.checkPath(self.pathEditLine.text())
        self.windowObject.show()



    def checkPath(self, pathOfFile):
        folder = self.pathEditLine.text()
        while os.path.exists(folder) != True:
            print("the specified path not exist")
            folder = self.pathEditLine.text()
        return folder

'''
get the userInput  from the EditLine
'''   
'''     
    def getText(self):
        inputUser = self.pathEditLine.text()
        print(inputUser)
'''
'''
function that exit from the system after clicking "cancel"
'''
def exit():
    sys.exit()

'''
define the methods to run only if this is the main module deing run
the name take __main__ string only if its the main running script and not imported 
nor being a child process
'''
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    PathMSGbox = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    pathUi = path_window(PathMSGbox)
    pathUi.pathCancelBtn.clicked.connect(exit)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I don't have any experience with Qt specifically, but most GUI libraries share this common behavior: if your function runs continuously until user input changes, then the window will lock up, and the user will not be able to change his input. The OS can only update your window and check for user input if you yield control to it, and you can't do that while you're inside a loop. Try to design your project so that all your functions end in a timely manner.

Comment: It's because you enter the while loop if `folder` does not exist, and then, you never create it. Therefore, you stay in the loop since `folder` will never exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you're calling `checkPath()` in the class initialization.

`checkPath()` read the path one time, and then start to evaluate if that path is valid 'forever'. This `while` loop running may even prevent the software to be able to effectively read again the text from `self.pathEditLine`.

Usually it's better to connect each function to an event:

- Check if the folder exist when a button is pressed
- Check if the folder exist when the text change
- Check if the folder exist when the user press enter

For doing any of these, you have to *connect* one of these events to the function:

button event:

```
self.btnMyNewButton.clicked.connect(checkPath)
```

text changing event:

```
self.pathEditLine.textChanged.connect(checkPath)
```

enter button event:

```
self.pathEditLine.returnPressed.connect(checkPath)
```

This means that you have to substitute one of the previous lines with the line where you call the `checkPath()` function in the initialization:

```
def __init__(self,windowObject ):
    self.windowObject = windowObject
    self.setupUi(windowObject)
    self.pathEditLine.textChanged.connect(checkPath)
    self.windowObject.show()
```

you also have to remove the `pathOfFile` argument from `checkPath(self, checkPath)` because you are not using it.

Since we decided a different behaviour for our `checkPath()` function, we no longer need a `while` loop: we will be reading the user input each time the `event` occurs, evaluate the user input, return the user input if we like it or return `False` if we don't:

```
def checkPath(self):
    folder = str(self.pathEditLine.text())
    if os.path.exists(folder):
        print '%s is a valid folder' % folder
        return folder
    else:
        print '%s is NOT a valid folder' % folder
        return False
```

Comment: i tried your answer but checkPath() function doesn't work  it just print the user input

Comment: I forgot to suggest you how to refactor your function, I'm editing the answer

Comment: so if i understand your answer right i need to connect each event that u suggested to the checkPath() function  right ?

Comment: not *each* event. Choose the behaviour you want and connect that event to the checkPath() function. You can even connect all the 3 events that i proposed to you (and other events too) to your function, so each time that any of these events occurs, your function is called